# business card reader for php

Tags: php, image-processing, contacts

I am trying to create a back-end for my application. In the back-end I will be receiving the business card in form of image (basically taken from mobile phone camera). I would like to process this image and extract the contact details like - the person's name, address, email etc and store it in database.

My back-end server supports PHP. So I am looking a PHP based solution for this. Or is there any web based API where I can send the image and get the contact fields in response.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please show some of the images.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need an [OCR](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2874-PHP-Recognize-text-objects-in-graphical-images.html). Secondly will the card contents be handwritten or printed? Both have their quirks. Expect a 70% success in that if the card is not oriented correctly (being tilted, not scanned correctly, having light exposures and stuff like that).

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, Contents will be printed on the card. I have tried going through the phpOCR. It seems like it only supports character recognition and that too on a monochrome graphical image. Whereas I am expecting reading of a graphical image that might not necessarily be monochrome. And also apart from just character recognizing, I would also like to have the contact details identified.

Comment: Hi, is the card with a specific design? If so you will have to know the boundaries of each field, then use an OCR engine. Generally it's better to use a QR code or something similar to the card to have an easier reading though.